# Environmental variable not working (Win 7) for a batch file (cake.bat from CakePHP)

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm getting started with CakePHP, and I'm trying to set my Windows 7's (64-bit) environmental variable PATH to recognize C:\xampp\htdocs\cakeblog\cake\console\cake.bat anywhere when using the command prompt.

I have set the environmental PATH variable for php.exe, and it is working great. However, when I was setting it, it didn't work when I added the path to the system variable. I had to add it to the user variable for it to work for some reason. I have no clue why this is so.

I tried doing the same for "C:\xampp\htdocs\cakeblog\cake\console," but it doesn't work for some reason neither in the system or user variable. I'm restarting the command prompt for the change broadcast to take effect, but it still doesn't work, while it works for php.exe. are .bat files different handled or something? I can't start the CakePHP baking process!

Any idea how to get this path included so that I can access cake.bat? Creating another .bat file (like runcake.bat) to directly run C:\xampp\htdocs\cakeblog\cake\console\cake.bat is not an option, as cake.bat creates files in the folder relative to where it's run. So, if I go to C:\xampp\htdocs\cakeblog\cake\console\ and run cake.bat, it will try to create files as C:\xampp\htdocs\cakeblog\cake\console as its root directory when I really want the files to be created somewhere like C:\mysite.. TIA!

My user path is below. cake.bat is located in the second directory.

```
C:\xampp\php; C:\xampp\htdocs\cakeblog\cake\console
```

UPDATE:
I just gave up with this approach and just wrote a short batch file named setpaths.bat that includes "set path=C:\xampp\htdocs\cakeblog\cake\console;C:\xampp\php" in it. This seems to override my user path variable and works great. I'll just have to run setpaths.bat every time I need to bake something.

Comment: post the content of the `path` variable, maybe it's something you overlooked.

Comment: Ah my bad. I put it up in the main post.

Comment: Have you tried running it from the powershell console ?

Comment: @ Nacereddine: no.. I'm not familiar with it. Is there anything wrong with the path? Maybe I need to take a nap and wake up later and take another look. I don't see anything odd about it.

Comment: No there is nothing wrong with the path you posted, but I was talking about the [environment path variable](http://i.imgur.com/RSblF.png). which require elements to be semi-colon separated (I was thinking that you may have forgotten one of them). As for powershell, it's like cmd on steroids (so everything you know from cmd will still work under powershell)

Comment: @ Nacereddine; I just gave up with this approach and just wrote a short batch file named setpaths.bat that includes "set path=C:\xampp\htdocs\cakeblog\cake\console;C:\xampp\php" in it. This seems to override my user path variable and works great.

Comment: I had a similar issue that I fixed by running the batch files as an administrator. Without administrator permissions, the batch file appeared not to use the folders that I set in the Path environmental variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Windows 7 environmental path variable is not working correctly for some reason. I have done the same thing on my home computer (same OS), and that one works just fine. I just gave up with this approach on my work computer and just wrote a short batch file named setpaths.bat that includes "set path=C:\xampp\htdocs\cakeblog\cake\console;C:\xampp\php" in it. This seems to override my user path variable and works great. The .bat file needs to be run during each session though. Hope this helps someone else who might be having a similar problem.

Answer (score 2):

A space after the semi-colon was the problem in my case.

Answer (score 0):

> C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\NVIDIA
>   Corporation\PhysX\Common;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program
>   Files\Intel\DMIX; **K:\Xampp\php;K:\Xampp\cake\cake\console;**
>   C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program
>   Files\TortoiseGit\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\

Make sure it's in the *Path* variable, try removing any spaces between semicolon and the next path. Just a wild guess.

Comment: I'll try it without the spaces next time. I'm editing the path variable of course.